# Magento 2 - need ONE store with multiple languages

Tags: magento2

Is their any way to enable languages (Japanese, Italian, French, Korean, Germen) for a single store ?

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Magento is using a separate store-view for each language.

So anyway to enable it in the config? the answer is No

Answer (score 0):

You should make different store-view for different language.

magneto already provide multi website, multi store and store has multi storeview (language).

you need to create multi storeview for your language.

Ref
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/stores-all-create-view.html

https://magefan.com/blog/configure-magento-2-multi-language-store

Comment: You get better idea from https://magefan.com/blog/configure-magento-2-multi-language-store